# Randomly moving circles in processing

Tags: functional-programming, processing

I have figured out how to make a circle move randomly, but now I want there to be 100 circles, but can't figure out how to add them, HELP!

```
float my_num = 10;
float n = random(5, 60); 
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  noStroke();
  smooth();
  rectMode(CENTER);
}
void draw() {
  background(0);

  translate(width * noise(my_num + 80), height * noise(my_num + 100));

  rotate(10 * noise(my_num + 40));

  ellipse(n, n, n, n);

  my_num = my_num + 0.02;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should create a Circle class that contains the position, size, color, etc of a circle.

Then create an ArrayList or array that contains 100 Circles, and loop through them whenever you want to update or draw those circles.

Recommended reading: http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/objects/fireworks